# Recursively search a directory, subdirectories, and files and print any with an uppercase letter in Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to create a function that will recursively search a directory, it's subdirectories, files and print out any that contain an uppercase letter. I've searched SO and other fourms for a way to do this and I've sorta got most of it working. However, I can't get it to print anything that contains an uppercase.

The folder structure would look like this:

```
rootfolder
 |-subfolder1
  |-filelower1
  |-filelower2
  |-fileUpper1
 |-subfolder2
  |-filelower4
 |-subFolder3
  |-fileUpper2
  |-fileupPer3
```

code:

```
def check_name():
    directory = r'Folder Path'

    for d in next(os.walk(directory))[1]:
        itempath = os.path.join(directory, d)
        path = d
        
        #this recursion is working as intended, this prints out if 
        # 'rootfolder' has an uppercase.
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in path):
            print("Found uppercase at:\n" + itempath)
        else:
            pass

    #this works correctly, but obviously this will print the entire path for
    #the directories and files, including the top level one, which isn't
    #how I would want this loop to work either way. 
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        for name in directories:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

I tried adjusting the second for loop to look like this:

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in files)
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        else:
            pass
    for name in directories:
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in directories)
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
        else:
            pass
```

but nothing printed. I assumed it was because I wasn't pointing inside the desired folder, so I adjusted the beginning to

`for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory)[2]:`

but I got TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable'.

Then, I tried adjusting it to

`for root, directories, files in next(os.walk(directory))[2]:`

but nothing was printed, but the code ran.

I'm not sure where else to go from here to get it working as intended

Comment: For the comparison, how about: `if x.lower() != x`, rather than character by character?

Comment: FYI. `else: pass` is just two superfluous lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `files` and `directories` with `name`

```
    for name in files:
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in name):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in directories:
        if any(letter.isupper() for letter in name):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes it's the most 'obvious' reason why something doesn't work :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a simple solution using the [`pathlib.Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) function:

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path(r'Folder Path')

# Recursively get all files with a capital letter in its path
for i in directory.rglob(r"[A-Z]*.*"):
    ...
```

The argument in `rglob` is the pattern the paths must match.
Notice the `.*`.
That will make files match and will prevent folders to match.
If you want to match just folders the pattern would be: `[A-Z]`.

It is important to notice that the regex `[A-Z]` will match every capital letter in the English alphabet.
If you had a path with characters such as `Ñ`, `Ç`… might not work as expected.

To get your path as an absolute path you can use [`Path.absolute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.absolute), but I think what you want is the relative path so use [`relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.absolute):

```
for i in directory.rglob(r"[A-Z]*.*"):
    print(i.relative_to(directory))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried runnign the code, and got the error 'ori_path' is not defined. Is this a unique name, or could anything be used there?

Comment: Sorry, My fault at copy-pasting. Try now.

Comment: That made it work! This does seem easier/simpler :) When I ran the code with the r"[A-Z*.*" it ended up printing files that were already lowercased, even if in a lowercase folder. Is that what was supposed to happen?

Comment: @Avila are you working on Windows? Case sensitive in Windows can be tricky...

Comment: @Avila after some research I found that if `rglob` is not case sensitive, you will need to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to filter what `rglob` yields. So maybe this is not a simple solution anymore...

Comment: windows, yes. But this may not be as simple, but it was still an amazing new thing to learn about :) So thank you still!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `os.walk()` like you used.

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(mypath):
    for name in (files + dirs):
        if name != name.lower():
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

I think `os.walk()` needs the full path. Which can be resolved by using `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mypath)`

The code would then look like:

```
import os

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), mypath)):
    for name in (files + dirs):
        if name != name.lower():
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```